# How to update the element of an array in mongo document using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, mongodb-query

here is my mongo document sample:

```
_id:ObjectId("60e54vfb99f346446618269")
count:Array
0:Object
   date:2021-07-03T15:13:42.200+00:00
   count:35
1:Object
   date:2021-07-03T15:13:42.200+00:34
   count:38
```

I am using node to handle api requests. I want to get the last element of the array from mongo and check the date if the date is a new date than the existing date, I want to insert that data. If it is the same as existing, I want to update the count in the exisitng date object.

How to do it in node? I'm using select and slice but I'm unable to get the last date and compare it. How to get the last element's date and compare it with request's date and post to the db?

This is the object I want to send:

```
router.route("/update/").put((req, res) =>{
    const count_update = {
        date: new Date(),
        count: req.body.count
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$cond` to check if the last element's `date` is greater than the input date
- `$substr` to get first 10 characters means "yyyy-mm-dd" from full date
- yes,

  - `$concatArrays` to concat current `count` array with new `date` and `count` fields object
- no,

  - `$map` to iterate loop of `count` array and check condition if `date` match with last element's date then update `count` field
  - `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated `count` object

```
var _id = "60e54vfb99f346446618269",
  date = new Date("2021-07-04T15:13:42.200+00:35"),
  count = 20;
var searchDate = date.toISOString().slice(0,10); // 2021-07-04

await SchemaModel.updateOne(
  { _id: _id },
  [{
    $set: {
      count: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $gt: [searchDate, { $substr: [{ $last: "$count.date" }, 0, 10] }]
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$count",
              [{ date: date, count: count }]
            ]
          },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$count",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $eq: ["$$this.date", { $last: "$count.date" }]
                      },
                      { count: count },
                      {}
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ac4dyqUTenn)

Comment: I highly appreciate your help @turivishal. But the problem is I want to check my date not time. I want to add a new object into the array only if the date differs. If it is different time of the same day I want to update the existing object.

Comment: *I want to check my date not time* => okay i will look into it. *I want to add a new object into the array only if the date differs* => this query is doing the same, if it is not just point out.

Comment: Yeah your answer is doing it. But it is inserting new object if the time differs. I don't want that. I want to add new object only if the day of the month changes.

Comment: In the case of "2021-07-03T15:13:42.200+00:34" and "2021-07-03T15:13:42.200+00:35", date is same right? but the time differs. I don't want to add new object if the time differs on the same day. I want to insert new object to the array only if it is a different day.

Comment: okay What is the datatype of the date field in collection? is it date type or string type?

Comment: it's date type. i used new Date()

Comment: I have another id inside my document other than the default _id. If I want to find by using that id and update, how should I change the code?

Comment: I tried your code and change the _id to id and pass my user id but it isn't working

Comment: you can pass in query `{ id: "123" }`

Comment: i don't know but how can i help you in this? make sure that you are missing something.

Comment: is await necessary?. it is throwing async error

Comment: I am not using a function. I edited the question. Check it.

Comment: put async before callback function `.put(async (req, res) =>`

Comment: Yes, I just found it and it is working. Thank you. But is there a limitation on how much post req we can send. Because after a certain point it isn't updating

Comment: i don't think any limitation about this, *after a certain point it isn't updating* => probably you are missing something.